# PhP order by today, week, month ... Not working

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to sort articles by "Today", "This Week", "This Month" , "All Time". The thing is that my query sums up votes from one table and gets articles from another table, this make query really complicated to me, And I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Anyway, I have a page like http://web.com/top.php?time=**"some time here"** And I use the following code to select articles basing on what time user chooses instead of **"some time here"**

```
$time = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_GET["time"]);

    if (!$time) { //Today
    $date = "WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) = 1";
    }
    else if ($time == "Week") { //This Week
    $date = "WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 7";
    }
    else if ($time == "Month") { //This Month
    $date = "WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 31";
    }
    else if ($time == "All") { //All Time
    $date = "";
    }
    else {
    header("Location: http://www.web.com/");
    exit;
    }

$sql = ("SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name ".$date." GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));
```

None of this seems to work ;D I don't see why, In my opinion it should, but than again I am relatively new to php and mysql. So could anyone suggest what the problem is here?

**My Database Structure to give you better understanding of the system.**

**Stories table**

[image]

---

**Votes table**

[image]

Comment: before you run your sql in your script print the variable $date to screen and see what the value is. then try running that in phpmyadmin and see if it is a php or a sql issue.

Comment: also do you really want to compare item_name (varchar) with id (int) ??

Comment: well, the $date is correct I echoed it out in all cases

Comment: what happens when you run your sql in phpmyadmin or equivalent substituting in the value returned in $date does that work?

Comment: @4t4 Those are old screenshot, I changed item_value to int(11)

Comment: @4t4 no it doesn't seem to work, returns no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    SELECT stories.*, SUM(votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' 
    FROM stories JOIN votes ON stories.id = votes.item_name 
    WHERE votes.item_name=$date 
    GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT 10
```

or similar, think about what you want to achieve and the logic then rewrite your sql query
in phpmyadmin till you get the right output before putting it into php.

Comment: votes.item_name=$date ? So for example where votes.item_name = TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 31 ?

Comment: ok this seems to work in phpmyadmin gona test it on a website now ))

Comment: Actualy when I use different queries e.g. TO_DAYS(stories.st_date) <= 7 (30 etc..)  It returns same results

Comment: you are ordering date by total votes, not by date. so it will always pick the top ten voted stories when item_name is the date returned. is this what you want?

Comment: Well, I want to select all articles that are, for example, one week old and order them by top votes.

Comment: The thing is, even when I get some results in phpMyAdmin I don't get anything on my website with a same query.

Comment: is that all of your script? you need to process the sql result into an array,    `$result=mysql_query($sql);`
    `$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);`
    `$num=mysql_num_rows($result);` etc and then print it to screen

Comment: try a subquery, do a select of all the articles ordered by date limited to the week/month. in the outer query join it to the votes and order by total votes descending and limit 10.

Answer (score 1):

start here

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

to get familiar with PHPs date function